# How to apply dynamic CSS class in 'v-for' according to the value of the element in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to apply positive or negative class as per the value in element which is part of v-for loop.

Below given is the template

```
<tr v-for='change in dispData'>
  <td>{{value}}</td> 
</tr
```

I want to add class named 'positive' if 'value>0' , else apply class 'negative'.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If any of the answers helped you solve the problem you should check it as the anwser. This will help other users as well

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. You can bind a class and thus use if statements.

```
<tr v-for='change in dispData'>
  <td :class="{positive: value > 0, negative: value === 0}">{{value}}</td> 
</tr>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Some notes (you will read this on the documentation):

- If you have some classes (like in the example: `font-size-20`) and add more dinamically with `:class`, then Vue will merge all of it, so you always will have the default classes defined with the standard html syntax.
- If your classes to add have special characters (like again `font-size-20`, basically if are not one-word classes) then you must wrap it as a string. ie: `:class="{'font-size-20': someCondition}`"

Basic example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    values: [1, 4, 0, -2, 20, -3, 0]
  }
})
```

```css
.font-size-20 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.positive {
  color: green;
}

.negative {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="example">
  <ul>
    <li 
      class="font-size-20"
      v-for="val in values"
      :class="{positive: val > 0, negative: val <= 0}"
    > {{ val }} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```